# Recursively return array of object and nested object keys

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

I am learning about recursion at the moment and have moved on from numbers, string and arrays into using it on objects... I'm trying to work out the best method for taking an object as an argument and collecting the keys of the object and all nested objects into an array

I can return the object keys of a single object not using recursion. So i was trying to create a variable as an empty array then iterate over the object using a for loop and if "i" is an object then push object keys into the array variable and return it. This wouldnt work unfortunate.

I would like the following:

```js
{lamp: 2, candle: 2, pillow: {big: 2, small: 4}, bathroom: {toilet: 1, shower: {shampoo: 1, conditioner: 2}}}
```

To return:

```js
[lamp, candle, pillow, big, small, bathroom, toilet, shower, shampoo, conditioner]
```

Hope this explains enough, let me know if not :)

I tried the following:

```js
function(obj) {
let keysArray = [];
for (let i = 0, i < obj.length, i++)
if (obj[i] === typeOf object) {
keysArray.push(obj[i].keys);
}
return keysArray
}
```

Comment: Post the code that you did try, even if it didn't work! It's good to give us a starting place.

Comment: Done, tried to quickly type up as I have moved on but that shows the direction i was going but I wanted to do it recursively

Comment: Appreciate this is way off.... but I'm in early days of learning

Comment: `for (let i = 0, i < obj.length, i++)` => That is valid for traverse an `array`, not an object. Checkout [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for traverse an object.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a recursive function as follows

```js
let obj = {lamp: 2, candle: 2, pillow: {big: 2, small: 4}, bathroom: {toilet: 1, shower: {shampoo: 1, conditioner: 2}}};

function getKeys(o) {
  let result = [];
  for (let key in o) {
    result.push(key);
    if(o[key] && typeof o[key] === "object") result.push(...getKeys(o[key]));
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(getKeys(obj));
```

Comment: Note that the `typeof null` is are also `"object"`. Depending on your context this might be an issue. To exclude this you could do `typeof o[key] === "object" && o[key] !== null`. Since normal objects are always evaluated to be truthy you could use the falsy property of `null` and instead do `typeof o[key] === "object" && o[key]`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have added it in my answer, however, based on the context, it seems to be an unlikely value.

Comment: I agree with you that the scenario is unlikely, but it's worth the mention.

Answer (score 1):

- You need to loop through the object using [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). The `for` loop is for arrays
- `obj[i] === typeOf object` is not correct. It should be `typeof obj[key] === "object"`.
- If the nested property is an object, you need to recursively call the function and `push` keys to `keysArray`

```js
function getKeys(obj) {
  let keysArray = [];
  
  for (let key in obj) {
    keysArray.push(key);
    
    if (typeof obj[key] === "object")
      keysArray.push(...getKeys(obj[key]))
  }
  return keysArray
}

const input={lamp:2,candle:2,pillow:{big:2,small:4},bathroom:{toilet:1,shower:{shampoo:1,conditioner:2}}}

console.log(getKeys(input))
```

FYI: `typeof null` is "object". So, the above code will throw an error if any of the properties are null. So, `Object(obj[k]) === obj[k]` can be used. This is true for all objects EXCEPT for null

Also, if [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatmap) is supported, you could do something like this

```js
const input={lamp:2,candle:2,pillow:{big:2,small:4},bathroom:{toilet:1,shower:{shampoo:1,conditioner:2}}};

const getKeys = obj =>
  Object.keys(obj).flatMap(key => Object(obj[key]) === obj[key] 
                                   ? [key, ...getKeys(obj[key])] 
                                   : key)

console.log(getKeys(input))
```

Comment: the conditional should be outside of the flatmap lambda - that way you don't accidentally run `Object.keys` on a non-object - even on the initial call

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
const keys = obj => Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc.push(key);
  return (obj[key] !== null && typeof obj[key] === 'object') // Avoid evaluating null as an object
    ? acc.concat(keys(obj[key])) 
    : acc;
}, []);
```

Usage:

```
keys({foo: 1, bar: {foobar: 2}}); // Outputs ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
```

Answer (score 0):

A very good use-case for generators. Here's a demonstration -

```js
const data =
  {lamp: 2, candle: 2, pillow: {big: 2, small: 4}, bathroom: {toilet: 1, shower: {shampoo: 1, conditioner: 2}}}

const keys = function* (o = {}) {
  if (Object(o) === o)
    for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(o)) {
      yield k
      yield* keys(v)
    }
}
  
console.log(Array.from(keys(data)))
// [lamp, candle, pillow, big, small, bathroom, toilet, shower, shampoo, conditioner]
```

Another solution is to use `Array.prototype.flatMap` -

```js
const data =
  {lamp: 2, candle: 2, pillow: {big: 2, small: 4}, bathroom: {toilet: 1, shower: {shampoo: 1, conditioner: 2}}}

const keys = (o = {}) =>
  Object(o) === o
    ? Object.entries(o).flatMap(([ k, v ]) =>
        [ k, ...keys(v) ]
      )
    : []
  
console.log(keys(data))
// [lamp, candle, pillow, big, small, bathroom, toilet, shower, shampoo, conditioner]
```